# Entire section of text turning into link #2

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preview should match the posted view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view)

The link text of the first link is expanded to the end of the next link. This just happened after my [last edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1432515/list) (#4). I have already found [the other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15474/entire-section-of-text-turning-into-link) describing a similar bug, but I don't have any bogus links in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432486/creating-object-instance-from-posted-data-php/1432515#1432515).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the '_' characters in the `__set_state()` and `var_export()` screwing with your markup?  Not sure.

Whatever happened, I fixed it by adding a "no-op" link to the post.

Either way, this is a dupe (or single-instance) of the more general "[Preview should match the posted view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view)" question.  Now that this specific post is fixed I'm going to mark this item as completed, but also add a link here from the other question so we can continue to track the larger issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new line in the [code view](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/84a71ac1-0f9f-4a2e-8777-a9db4603a022/view-source) of your post. I don't know if this has anything to do with this problem (maybe just a word wrap), but I would set the first link anew.